# Adapting Smartphone Camera to derive Blackbody temperature

Tags: camera, physics, detection, temperature, infrared

At first blush this presumably means -

(1) looking only at lower IR frequencies,

(2) select a IR frequency cut-off for low frequency buckets of the u/v FFT grid

(3) Once we have that, derive the power distribution - squares of amplitudes - for that IR range of frequency buckets the camera supports.

(4) Fit that distribution against the Rayleigh-Jones classical Black Box radiation formula:
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law#Other_forms_of_Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law)

(5) Assign a Temperature of 'best fit'.

The units for B(ν,T) are Power per unit frequency per unit surface area at equilibrium Temperature

Of course, this leaves many details out, such as (6) cancelling background, etc, but one could perhaps use the opposite facing camera to assist in that. Where buckets do not straddle the temperature of interest, (7) use a one-sided distribution to derive an inferred Gaussian curve to fit the Rayleigh-Jeans curve at that derived central frequency ν, for measured temperature T.

Finally (8) check if this procedure can consistently detect a high vs low surface temperature (9) check if it can consistently identify a 'fever' temperature (say, 101 Fahrenheit / 38 Celcius) pointing at a forehead.

If all that can be done, (10) Voila! a body fever detector

So those who are capable can fill us in on whether this is possible to do so for eventual posting at an app store as a free Covid19 safe body temperature app? I have a strong sense there's quite a few out there who can verify this in a week or two!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the analog signal assumed in (1) and (2) are not available in the Android digital Camera2 interface.

Android RAW image stream, that is uncompressed YUV, is already encoded Y green monochrome, and U,V are blue and red shifts from zero for converting green monochrome to color.

The original analog frequency / energy signal is not immediately accessible. So adaptation is not possible (yet).